# SPAM appears at the beginning of the message title

Tags: python, django, email, sendmail, spam

I have a problem with sending email messages. When I send a message from the contact form in django 1.5 and receive a message - the word SPAM appears at the beginning of the message title.
Email address is not on blacklist.

When I am sending message on my local machine, everything is OK.

```
    email = EmailMessage(
        'Contact',
        message,
        'mail@from.com',
        [form.cleaned_data['email'] ],
        ['bcc@addressbcc.com'],
        headers={'X-PremiumMailfilter-Spam-Flag': 'NO'},
    )
    email.send()
```

Comment: The prefix is probably being added by the receiving mail server because the message has been identified as suspicious - this is not something that you can change on the sending server. Also, side note, Django 1.5 reached end of life in 2014. You *really* should not be using it in production.